# How to use Vue-CLI-service serve on HTTP-2?

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server, http2, vue-cli, network-protocols

By default, **Vue-CLI-service** serves on HTTP 1.1. Is there any way to serve it on **HTTP-2**?

Answer (score 0):

[Vue CLI's `devServer` configuration](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) is passed to the underlying Webpack, so you could set [`devServer.http2=true`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttp2) to enable HTTP2. Note that [`devServer.https=true`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps) is also needed for Vue CLI to use HTTPS (required for HTTP2 to work):

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    https: true,
    http2: true,
  }
}
```

Despite Webpack's deprecation warnings for both the options above, this configuration actually works for the current version of Webpack (version `5.65.0`) used by Vue CLI `5.0.0-rc.1`. Switching to `devServer.server=spdy` without enabling `devServer.https` does not work.